# Не срабатывает DataSource при CollectionView.reloadData()

Tags: swift, ui, uicollectionview

**Цель:**
Когда пользователей нажимает кнопку, получить результат из Firebase и отрисовать его в CollectionView.

**Что сейчас:**
При первом заходе в приложения я делаю запрос к Firebase и получаю ответ, все отрисовывается как нужно, ячейки на месте, коллекция тоже. Ячейка у меня кастомная и сделана в `.xib` файле.
Теперь когда я реализовал логику получения другой информации, я меняю только одно слово, чтобы данные получал из firebase уже другие. В дебагере проверил, массив который в DataSource после нажатия содержит новые данные, логика отработала, но после `collectionView.reloadData()` ничего не происходит. Ошибок нет. Только есть не делать проверку на nil, тогда да, приложуха падает на collectionView

По дебагеру: `collectionView - nil`, `numberOfItemsInSection` - не вызывается и ячейки не обновляются (тем самым и UI не обновляется)..

**Что пробовал:**
Код получения данных был у меня в фоновом потоке, `reloadData` делал в главном, убрал потоки, потому что думал проблемы с потоками - не помогло. Пытался найти решения, в основном ответы были что-то типа: " Вы пытаетесь обновить данные в фоновом потоке" или "У вас коллекция не связанная с IB" и тд,  не относятся к моей проблеме.

**Код:**
Я постараюсь выложить то, что нужно.

```
// метод который срабатывает при получение интерактива от пользователя, как я сказал
// до строчки с reload все работает, а после ничего не происходит
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            self.db.collection(K.FStore.collectionName!)
              .order(by: "date", descending: true)
              .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in

              if let e = error {
                  print("Ошибка при получение карточек \(e)")
              } else {
                  self.cards = []
                  if let snap = querySnapshot?.documents {
                     for item in snap {
                        let data = item.data()
                        if let fio = data[K.FStore.fullName] as? String, let price = data[K.FStore.price] as? String, let phone = data[K.FStore.phone] as? String, let description = data[K.FStore.description] as? String, let address = data[K.FStore.address] as? String {

                          let newCard = Card(fio: fio, phone: phone, price: price, description: description, address: address, idCard: item.documentID)  
                            self.cards.append(newCard)
                         }
                      }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
// self.cards - это массив Card, где есть определенная информация по карточке, потом Card я сделал в Cell ( т.е. кастомная ячейка - это карточка
```

```
// UICollectionViewDataSource
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return cards.count
    }

//cellForItemAt
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

       let cardCell: Card

       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: K.cellMainScreenIndet, for: indexPath) as! MainCellCollectionView

       cardCell = cards[indexPath.row]

       cell.fioLabel.text = cardCell.fio
       cell.priceLabel.text = cardCell.price
       cell.addressLabel.text = cardCell.address
       cell.discriptionLabel.text = cardCell.description
       cell.phoneLabel.text = cardCell.phone

       return cell
   }
```

Надеюсь на Вашу помощь, так как новичок еще полный и не понимаю, где я ошибся и почему так работает язык!

Comment: `collectionView` у вас nil? Как так получается, если первоначально данные грузятся

Comment: Вот именно)) В этом то вся проблема) На этот моменте я встал, как камень. В коде который я представил не хватает одной детали , так это проверки `if .. else` на то, что выбрал пользователь ( не очень важная деталь, я уверен не в этом деле проблема, ведь как раз по этому выбору идет запрос в Firebase. А дальше да, `CollectionView` без `?` будет вылетать и на проверке во второй раз - это `nil`

Comment: Тестовый проект можете куда-то залить для воспроизведения проблемы? Возможно с доступом к тестовой базе

Comment: да, загрузите весь проект куда-нибудь, поможем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взял исходный код [здесь](https://github.com/AntonBrock/kwik)

По порядку:

1. collectionView nil потому что MenuViewController написано
   `let vc: MainViewController = MainViewController()`,
   а collectionView является @IBOutlet, если инитить из сторибоарда
   надо делать так

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController") as? MainViewController
```

2. В `MenuViewController` происходит управление совершенно другим инстансом `MainViewController`, чтобы управлять нужным `MainViewController` должен о себе как-то сообщить, например переопределить `prepare for segue` следующим образом

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let menuNavigationController = segue.destination as? SideMenuNavigationController,
            let menuViewController = menuNavigationController.viewControllers.first as? MenuViewController {
                menuViewController.mainViewController = self
        }
    }
```

а в `MenuViewController` заменить

```
let vc: MainViewController = MainViewController()
```

на

```
weak var mainViewController: MainViewController?
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за Ваше время! Я сделал все, как Вы написали, но, к сожалению, ошибка сохранилась. Вот мои шаги:

1) Я добавил в `MenuViewController`: 
`
var board = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
lazy var controller = board.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as? MainViewController
` 
2) Там же заменил `let vc` на то, что вы указали  

3) В `MainViewController` добавил `override func prepare..`

Надеюсь, на Ваш ответ!

Comment: 1 шаг не нужен, это просто чтобы объяснить, только второй. Я сделал тоже самое, и у меня работает

Comment: На всякий случай добавил ПР на исправление в твоем репозитории

Comment: Огромное спасибо за pr и объяснение! Вы очень мне помогли и решили мою проблему! Еще раз, огромное спасибо!